# How to get banners clients when exists banners with this client?

Tags: mysql, com-banners

I need to retrieve the banners_clients data only when exists banners for this client id:

Example:

banner one - client id 1

banner two - client id 1

banner three - client id 4

client id 1 - name John

client id 2 - name Lucy

client id 3 - name Holga

client id 4 - name Jorge

---- after fetch data ---

client id 1 - name John

client id   4 - name Jorge

https://pastebin.com/UCMrRT72

Answer (score 1):

Join the banners table.

```
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('a.id','a.name','contact','email','extrainfo','state','checked_out','checked_out_time','metakey','own_prefix','metakey_prefix','purchase_type','track_clicks','track_impressions')));
$query->from('#__banner_clients a')
  ->join('inner', '#__banners b ON b.client_id = a.id');
```

Comment: Table 'carrosde_newclass.#__banner_clients a' doesn't exist

Comment: Please see my edited code

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('a.*');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__banner_clients', 'a'))
->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__banners', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('b.cid') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('a.id') . ')')
->order($db->quoteName('a.name') . 'ASC');
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: If this is the solution that you implemented, please mark your answer with the green tick.  This will prevent the system from bumping this page to the top of the questions list for new volunteer attention.